# Switch between full-screen windows of the same application in Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard, xcode, fullscreen

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Lion for navigating through my open full screen Xcode projects? ⌘~ is not working.

Comment: Yeah, "cmd" + "~" doesn't switch between Spaces in Lion. It only switches between windows on a particular space. I wonder if it's a bug in Lion, or purposely designed that way.

Comment: @PaulEccles Both *Move focus to next window (in application)* and *Move focus to active or next window* behaved the same way in Snow Leopard.

Comment: @PaulEccles IMO this is a bug (anything that doesn't behave as expected is a bug).  cmd-~ moves focus between windows of the same application.  It should obviously do this regardless of whether or not the windows are fullscreen.

Comment: Is there anything in Mavericks to solve this problem?

Comment: see [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/151090/13303) for a (paid) solution. No affiliation on my part. A shame Apple still hasn't fixed this.

Comment: It only seems to work if you have multiple application windows within the same space. For example, if I run Matlab, and run the 'plot' command to bring up a graph, I can toggle between the graph and the editor while the editor is in full screen mode.

Answer (score 11):

You can switch between spaces using ctrl + left right arrow keys, but this can be used with all spaces not just Xcode

Comment: Indeed "ctrl" + "left right arrow" or "ctrl" + "number", are very useful in order to navigate through spaces, but what I'm missing is a shortcut imitating the "cmd" + "~" in full-screen open windows of the same app.

Answer (score 2):

I can switch between windows of the same program by dragging four fingers left or right across the trackpad.  This is analogous to pressing [Command] + [~] when the windows are not in fullscreen.

You can find this setting under System Preferences>Trackpad>More Gestures.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually allows switching between multiple full screen instances of the same application that I have found.  Works nicely and allows staying full screen.

Comment: I don't see any gesture that fits given description. And no option for four-finger swipe either

Comment: this cycles through all other maximized applications as well.  so no, it's not like `cmd+~`.

Comment: This allows to switch between different fullscreen windows, not between windows _of the same program_. It seems to be the an okay workaround, but it's not a direct solution to the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the perfect solution as its a paid one, but this software called [Which](http://manytricks.com/witch/) fills this gap. As this is truly a bothersome problem (I often use five or six RDP connections at one time in full screen) I thought I would mention it.

disclaimer : I am not affiliated to this program.

Answer (score 0):

You an also use Ctrl+Number to switch to a numbered desktop.  However, full-screen apps are not given a number and so can't directly be used with this technique.  However, if you like the approach, you could manually resize XCode to fill a desktop without actually using full-screen,

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the swipe two fingers left/right mouse gesture to change between full-screen windows of the same application. See Settings>Mouse>More Gestures

Comment: Seems to require three fingers rather than two.

Comment: 3 fingers. plus this cycles through all other maximized applications as well. so no, it's not like `cmd+~`.

Answer (score 0):

### BEST SOLUTION, but NOT NATIVE:

**Witch for Mac**

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/witch/id412485838?mt=12
- https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17185/witch

it will do exactly this and let you customize exactly which shortcuts keys to switch between any windows of same app, just those in foreground, just those minimized, or many other combinations of those and much more functionality:

Answer (score 0):

my 'toolbox' for these problems are:

- Use maximize instead of fullscreen (alt+click_on_green_icon) so I can use ctrl+1/2/3/4 and
- Double-tab with two fingers in the dock to get app-expose.
- use mission control or four-finger-swipe or ctrl+left/right
- the app hyperswitch so cmd-tab AND alt+tab or cmd+^/~ is usable again.
- the app hyperdock
- hardly using but also helping: the app ubar (not so sweet) or witch, already named.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lwouis/alt-tab-macos does this.

https://github.com/mandrigin/AlfredSwitchWindows might also work, but I have not tested it.