# Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump directly to a particular full screen app in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, fullscreen

When you full screen an application in Lion, it "flies out" of the desktop space it started in, and winds up at the end of the spaces list (assuming you have turned off auto-arranging).

As a result if the app being pulled out of the spaces flow, there is no way to ctrl+1/2/3etc to jump to the space it is currently occupying.

Does anyone know how you can make a keyboard shortcut so you can jump directly to full screened apps?

Comment: Do you want the shortcut to launch the app into a full screen space or just select one that is already there?

Comment: i want to leave the app running in full screen and be able to switch to it using ctrl+1/2/3/4/5 etc

Answer (score 3):

If you want this for a specific app, you could use an application like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) to set up a shortcut to switch to that application.

If you want this for every app, I don't think it is possible at the moment. It may come with an update (as the ability to manually re-arrange spaces in Mission Control).

Waiting for a better solution, you can still use ⌃→ and ⌃← to navigate between spaces (including fullscreen applications).

Comment: In addition to Keyboard Maestro, Alfred and Spark also allow global keyboard shortcuts to launch or switch to apps. This won't help you if its a multi-window app though.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just use Command-Tab switching, holding tab for the appropriate length of time to reach the app you'd like to switch to.

This sadly works less well with apps that can own multiple full screen spaces, or which can exist as both a full screen window, and another separate window on another desktop.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/switch-between-full-screen-windows-of-the-same-application-in-lion for the lamentable omission of ability to switch between windows if they are on different spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with this also and found a solution.

I assume that almost all of you realizes immediately what this is about. So the
**Short answer: Install better touch tool and define a gesture from predefined action called "send keyboard shortcut to specific application".**

Long answer:

1. Install bettertouch tool (http://blog.boastr.net/) and open it.
2. Define the gesture for global. From the top you can define in which way you want to input the action. I used trackpad input, but this works almost in same way for other inputs also.
3. From down-right corner click "add new gesture". Choose a gesture you like under "touchpad gesture". Then choose predefined action from right and select "Send keyboard shortcut to specific application". You can leave the command field empty and just choose the application. Be sure to select the "bring app to front before.."-option.
4. You are done.

(5. example) I have defined four finger swipes to switch between spaces. I switch between spotify and chrome a lot. So I defined two finger swipes from left and right edges to jump to chrome and spotify. For spotify I defined also shortcut "alt+cmd+F" so it jumps directly to search field when I do the swipe.

Just realized this so I bet that other awesome actions could be done through this also. Hope this helps.