# Keyboard shortcut for switching to an open full-screen preview window

Tags: macos, preview, fullscreen

If I have a document open in full-screen mode in Preview, and other documents open in windowed mode, I can switch FROM the full-screen window to other applications with CMD+TAB, and I can cycle the other windows with CMD+` , but how can I, with the keyboard, switch back to the fullscreen window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the option to switch to a space with open windows for an application is checked in the Mission Control preferences and the application has no other windows, you can just select it from the application switcher or Spotlight.

Control-left, control-right, and control-numbers should change spaces by default; the shortcuts can be changed in the keyboard preferences.

Related questions:

- [Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump directly to a particular full screen app in Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21370/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-jump-directly-to-a-particular-full-screen-app-in?rq=1)
- [Switch between full-screen windows of the same application in Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/switch-between-full-screen-windows-of-the-same-application-in-lion?lq=1)
- [shortcuts - Assign a key to switch to fullscreen instance of MacVim](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51274/assign-a-key-to-switch-to-fullscreen-instance-of-macvim?lq=1)
- [Shortcut To Full Screen App In Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/423240/shortcut-to-full-screen-app-in-lion)