# Is there a keyboard shortcut to navigate full screen windows of the same application?

Tags: fullscreen

Or is there some app that will let me do it. This bug has been forever since Lion. Isn't it about time apple fixed it?

Comment: You mean to switch between different desktops which are on the fullscreen mode of the same app?

Comment: Why not use ⌘`?

Comment: @SridharRatnakumar it does not work with full screen windows of same app. My favorites that I use often - iTerm, IntelliJ or even Firefox, Safari - just open multiple full screen windows of the app. I wish ⌘` would work in those cases as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Contexts for Mac](https://contexts.co/). I replaced the built-in apps switcher with this utility which lets me to view full screen windows including a feature to search active windows by title.

Answer (score 2):

[Witch](http://manytricks.com/witch/) also includes full screen windows, and ⌥⇥ selects the next window from the current application by default.

Or if you use an application that has its own implementation for full screen windows (like WriteRoom), ⌘` usually includes custom full screen windows.

Comment: Thanks a zillion. My question is pretty much a dupe of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20883/switch-between-full-screen-windows-of-the-same-application-in-lion but I was looking for solutions and you have given a great one. Thanks much.

Comment: After trying it a bit, I am not liking it much. :( . I hope Apple will do something about it in the next OS release.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like ⌘-tab, but restricted to windows of the same application?  I indeed installed Witch in the past for the ⌥-tab option, but don't use it anymore, either.

- I am using fullscreen windows a lot, but I am just using ⌘-tab and Ctrl-left/right for navigating between spaces.
- Maybe using tabs within the same full-screen window is another possible workaround (depending on the application)?  E.g. in Safari, [Shift-]Ctrl-tab works, and in Terminal, it's ⌘-}/{